# Simulating a columnar store using cluster tables

Tags: oracle, database-design

I have a client that mostly uses calculations on a single column of many rows from a table (each time another column), which is classic for a columnar DB.
The problem is that he is using Oracle, so what I thought of doing was to build a bunch of cluster table where each table has just one column besides the PK and this way allow him to work in a pseudo-columnar model.

What are you thoughts on the subject?
Will it even work as expected or am I just forcing the solution here ?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Interesting question, but whats the problem the client is experiencing?  Slow queries?  Before you re-arch the db, maybe look into the existing queries and indexes (you may have done this already tho).  Also, a basic example of their setup and typical queries would be helpful

Comment: Do you always aggregated a field from all rows, or some subset of rows? If latter, what is the filtering criteria?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it in the end but I did achieve close to vertical performance time using sorted table hash cluster.

Comment: Late to the party, but bitmap indexes might have been a handy choice.